# Silverlight not working

Tags: windows

When I try to load a Silverlight application in the Tor Browser, I get an error saying Silverlight could not be found. I clicked yes when it asked me if the browser should load external content but when I tried to uncheck the 'Disable plug-ins'-checkbox in Preferences it would automatically check it again.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: See https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBFlash for a similar question about Flash.

Comment: Have you allowed Silverlight in the settings of Tor Browser (NoScript add-on)?

Comment: No activity since March so I decided to close the question.